# Unable to connect to nodejs app from react app (inside driver docker app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-network

I have a nodeJS app running in one of the docker container lets say `socketserver` and i have a react app running in another container `reactjs`

I am connecting both on the same network `driver`.

when i run the reactjs app from chrome browser using the port mapping provided during the docker run creation, it shows me below error:

[image]

Here is the docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  dashboard-server:
    container_name: socketserver
    image: qr-socket-server
    networks:
      - backend
  sample:
    container_name: sample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
networks:
  frontend:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    # Use a custom driver which takes special options
    driver: bridge
```

**PS**: I have tried creating a alpine image and ping the nodejs container from there using the `http://socketserver:30100` and it is returning a correct response...

Comment: Is that screenshot from a browser window?  The browser isn't running inside Docker and can't resolve container names as host names.

Comment: Correct. its from the browser window... how do i run from inside docker?

Comment: You can't.  You need to publish `ports:` from your front-end container, and connect to that published port using the host's DNS name (or `localhost`, if the browser and containers are running on the same system).

Comment: oh ok... i tried the same... still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to publish the port of both service, e.g.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  dashboard-server:
    container_name: socketserver
    image: qr-socket-server
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3000:80
  sample:
    container_name: sample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - 3001:80
networks:
  frontend:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    # Use a custom driver which takes special options
    driver: bridge
```

Second, if the request to `socketserver` is done by the code loaded in the browser, you don't have to use `http://socketserver:3000` instead, you should use `http://localhost:3000`, but, if the request is done by the backend of your web application you must use `http://socketserver:3000`